# Access denied MYSQL error for root@localhost

Tags: php, mysql, apache, laravel

I am trying to migrate the database on a Apache server. I can login to the mysql on the server by doing `mysql -u root - p` and entering my `root` password.

I have set up global permissions for the `root` user by using this command:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

In my Laravel DB config file I am doing this:

```
'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'my_db',
            'username'  => 'root',
            'password'  => 'password',
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),
```

When I try and run the migration on the server

```
[PDOException]                                                                          
SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Here are the permissions are well:

[image]

Comment: have you tried switching the config to point to 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost?

Comment: Yes the password is correct and this is just a placeholder.

Comment: No, 127.0.0.1 doesn't work.

Comment: is it complaining about driver or something else when you switch to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: @alihaider it was but I then installed the correct php5-mysql and the same error returned.

Comment: Did you do: `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` after setting them?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and what I did wrong was that I went to the old address (`http://localhost`) and not the new vagrant one (`http://localhost:8080` or whatever it is set to). Kind of silly I know...